# Looking for a Quad 3−State Noninverting Buffers in DIP package

Tags: buffer, tri-state, dip

My application is a half-duplex serial communication (2 buffers) and a switch for a 35 to 60mA load (1 buffer). I found On Semi MC74HC126AN (https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/h52tembhav/ONSMS12940-1.pdf), but it's limited at 35mA load. Is there anything similar in DIP package with a bit higher load limit. More buffers would be acceptable. Can I parallel 2 buffers for increased load?

---

This is the diagram of serial bus (1Mbps, 5V TTL, Dynamixel servo):

[image]

The load is a small laser, which needs at least 3.3V.

Comment: Why do you need it to be in DIP? That's going to severely limit your options.

Comment: @Hearth I have to hand solder a dozen boards and it goes much faster with through-hole components.

Comment: The 35mA is an absolute maximum rating. It means you do not get anywhere near it under normal intended operating conditions. The output voltage will drop by a hefty amount even at few mA of current. These are buffers, not load switches, they are not intended to power a load. Sure more powerful logic series than HC exists, but expecting to power 35 to 60mA with no appreciable voltage drop is just too much. Other than that, asking for part suggestions what to buy is off-topic.

Comment: What is the logic level and which baudrate do you use? Can you please provide the intended circuit diagram?

Comment: @Jens Added more info.

Comment: I worked with Dynamixel servos using a similar interface as you do. Why do you need to drive 60 mA? The servo input draws below 5 mA only.

Comment: @Jens I need to drive the laser at up to 60mA, not the serial bus, but trying to use just one chip if feasible.

Comment: You can use drivers in parallel, no problem. There are stronger versions as the LS variant of this bus driver. Provide a good VCC decoupling capacitor. I had 33 ohm in series to the Dynamixel bus to reduce EMI emissions.

Comment: @Jens Thank you. Can you post your schematic of Dynamixel interface? What LS part you had in mind? I checked SN74LS126ANSR and the output is rated at 24mA.

Comment: `Can I parallel buffers for increased load?` I can't remember that specified anywhere, but especially with CD4000-series hex buffers/drivers (4049/50) this was commonplace. (More than 20 mA, imagine that... at 15 V, all six ganged together.)

Comment: `60 mA` sinking, sourcing, or both? I guess dedicated "74xx-series" LED drivers (5300/02) is cheating?

Comment: @greybeard *sinking, sourcing* any one of these two would work.

Answer (score 1):

I used 2 single gate chips for my dynamixel interface. This uses less board space than the e.g. the LS241.

This is a fragment of my circuit with some ESD and lost servo GND protection. My customers tend to hot swap things like servos.

The used MCU is a 3.3 V Teensy 3.6 or 4.1.

R79 and R64 are just there to define the signal level if the Teensy module is not mounted during board tests.

If I had to drive a laser as well, I would probably use a separate MOSFET or "digital transistor" for this, but I don't know your application.

[image: Dynamixel servo interface]

Comment: There is a typo, IC04 is 74LVC1G07GW